# If Statement not swicthing correctly

Tags: php, if-statement

I have these 3 if statements which depending on the value in the variable will either put it into one column or another. But for some reason it always uses only one of the 3 even if the if statement should be false. I have placed the code below. Thanks for any help.

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$link) {
  // error happened
  print(0);
}
mysql_select_db('test');

// sanitize the value
$value = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['uname']);
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);

if($value == "Paid" || "Waiting on Payment"){
  $sql = "UPDATE test SET payment='$value' WHERE id='$id'";
}

if($value == "Repaired" || "Waiting on Repairs"){
  $sql = "UPDATE test SET repair='$value' WHERE id='$id'";
}

if($value == "With Student" || "Awaiting Pickup"){   //Always uses this one for somereason unknown to me..
  $sql = "UPDATE test SET returned='$value' WHERE id='$id'";
}

// start the query
// check if the query was executed
if(mysql_query($sql, $link)){
  // everything is Ok, the data was inserted
  print(1);
  echo $sql;    
} else {
  // error happened
  print(0);
}

?>
```

Comment: please write a meaning full title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous solutions don't address the problem.

What you need to use is the *if-else* block after *if*.

```
if(conditionA is true){
  //do taskA
}
else if(conditionB is true){
  //do taskB
}
else if(condition is true){
  //do taskC
}
else {
  //do taskD
}
```

That answers your question.

But then comes the next problem, which is answered @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/10492151/260034 by "A Bag". It is because the strings "Waiting on Payment", "Waiting on Repairs", etc always get evaluated to TRUE. So even if $value is not equal to "Paid", the string "Waiting on Payment" evaluates to TRUE.

The OR operator || returns TRUE if either of the 2 operands evaluates to TRUE.

So all your *if* statements evaluate to TRUE and since you have a bunch of *if* statements and not an if-ifelse block, the block of code in your last *if* condition **seems** to be the one which is always executing.

The revised code would be something like,

```
if($value == "Paid" || $value == "Waiting on Payment"){
  $sql = "UPDATE test SET payment='$value' WHERE id='$id'";
}
else if($value == "Repaired" || $value == "Waiting on Repairs"){
  $sql = "UPDATE test SET repair='$value' WHERE id='$id'";
}
else if($value == "With Student" || $value == "Awaiting Pickup"){
  $sql = "UPDATE test SET returned='$value' WHERE id='$id'";
}
```

Comment: what it be possible to use something else instead of 3 if statements or is that the most practical soultion in this situtation

Comment: @Matthew: You can use a `switch`-statement, I've posted an answer for this.

Comment: The revised code is [incorrect](http://codepad.org/ECp397Io). Every `||` will evaluate to `true`, and therefore the first `if` statement will be taken if `$value` equals `true`.

Answer (score 3):

```
if($value == "Paid" || "Waiting on Payment"){
```

should be

```
if($value == "Paid" || $value =="Waiting on Payment"){
```

SWITCH version

```
     switch ($value) {
        case 'Paid':
        case 'Waiting on Payment'
            $sql = "UPDATE test SET payment='$value' WHERE id='$id'";
            break;
        case 'Repaired':
        case 'Waiting on Repairs':
            $sql = "UPDATE test SET repair='$value' WHERE id='$id'";
            break;
        case 'With Student':
        case "Awaiting Pickup":
            $sql = "UPDATE test SET returned='$value' WHERE id='$id'";
            break;
    }
```

Comment: once you get to 3 i usually use  case\switch  as being a little cleaner

Answer (score 0):

> i know this is off topic but is there any other way to accomplish this without using 3 individual if statements? – Matthew

```
switch($value)
{
    case "Paid":
    case "Waiting on Payment":
        $column = "payment";
        break;
    case "Repaired":
    case "Waiting on Repairs":
        $column = "repair";
        break;
    case "With Student":
    case "Awaiting Pickup":
        $column = "returned";
        break;
    default:
        die("TODO: Error handling for unknown value: ".$value);
}

$sql = "UPDATE test SET ".$column." = '".$value."' WHERE id='".$id."'";
```